# Why is JSON not accepting a stored procedure passing variable as Id?

Tags: sql-server, json, stored-procedures

Here I write a stored procedure for deleting records; it's working fine in SQL. But when I try to load it in MVC JSON format it threw an error:

> implementation of the query pattern for source type 'int'. 'Select' not found"

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[AccessorDataDelById]
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Accessors
    WHERE Id = @ID
END
```

JSON format:

```
public JsonResult GetAssdata(int iD = 0)
{
    var x = (from n in db.AccessorDataDelById(iD)
             select n).FirstOrDefault();

    return new JsonResult { Data = x, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: `DELETE` doesn't return a result set - hence, you cannot "select" from it ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=db.AccessorDataDelById(iD)
```